# Call to a method or determine if method is working/exists?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, methods

Is there a way that vba can determine if a method is present/available?I have two different methods that will essentially be doing the same thing, but in different ways: one being an SQL server and the other being an excel file. I want to be able to first call the SQL method, and if whatever reason that SQL method is unavailable, it will then call the excel method. But what would be the line of code in the if statement?

I know that you "Call" to methods, but what essentially is the line of code that would be:

```
If SQLMethod() ... Then 
   Call SQLMethod()
Else
   Call ExcelMethod()
End If
```

What would the code be at "..." to check this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't quite understand, you are asking first the SQL method and if it isn't available, the code or the SQL server?

Comment: So i want the SQL method to be the first priority. When this macro is executed, I want it to check to make sure that the SQL is available. So within this SQL method, there is code that will determine if the method is connected to the actual server its on. If isn't, then I want the SQL method to be able to say that it's not available to access. In which the macro will then go to the Excel method

Comment: The SQL method is connecting to a SQL database, and the excel method is a excel file that has the same information that will be in the SQL database. They are essentially doing the same exact procedure. However, I want the macro to execute the SQL method, and if for whatever reason that method is unavailable, it will then select the Excel method and execute the code in that method

Comment: If the SQL method is returning an array, an object or a string. Turn your method into a `Function` and then set your object/variable to this function. If after the SQL Function your object remains empty, then hit the excel method

Comment: Basically the Excel file is a backup way to store information if for whatever reason the SQL server goes down

Comment: Then I'd declare a `variant` variable such as: `Dim MySQL As Variant` then, `MySQL = SQLFunction` if after this your `MySQL` is empty, then do the same with the  `ExcelFunction`

Comment: Alright, I'll try this. Thank you!

Comment: You could just return a Boolean from your `SQLMethod` (True = function worked, False = function didn't work). You can then have an `IF` statement: `If Not SQLMethod Then ExcelMethod`. This will first call `SQLMethod`. If that's not successful, it will call `ExcelMethod`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a reference to a routine that doesn't exist; the code won't compile, and you'll receive a "Complie error: Sub or Function not defined".

But, you can do this:

```
Sub Main()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.Run "Test1"
    If Err <> 0 Then Application.Run "Test2"
End Sub

Sub Test1()
    Debug.Print "Test1()"
End Sub

Sub Test2()
    Debug.Print "Test2()"
End Sub
```